# Select element in frame of frame

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have webpage with this structure:

```
<frameset>
    <frameset><frame name="f0"></frame></frameset>
    <frame>
        <frameset>
            <frame name="f1"></frame>
            <frame name="f2"></frame>
        </frameset>
    </frame>
</frameset>
```

I am on frame f1 and I need to get some element from frame f2. window[1] is the frame f2.

I have tried this code and many others and no success

```
var $up = $('a.myA', window[0].document);
$up.attr('title', "bla");
```

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

with

```
window.parent.frames[0].document
```

I can get to content of frame f0. Still don't know how to get to the other ones.

Comment: `$(window.parent).find('[name="f2"]').contents()`

Comment: doesnt work. check my edited question

Comment: Oh, wait, those aren't iframes, those are framesets? Holy crap, haven't seen those since the nineties, noone uses framesets anymore.

Comment: anyway, you can just do `$('[name="f2"]')` to access that, it's just DOM elements

Comment: Yes, framesets :/ and I cant change them, have to work with them.
$('[name="f2"]') doesnt work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var f2Frame = parent.document.querySelector("[name=f2]");
var f2FrameDocument = f2Frame.contentDocument || f2Frame.contentWindow.document;
f2FrameDocument.title = "bla";
```

I think this should do the job. But I wasn't able to test it.
Of course you have to keep an eye on the same origin policy (see Krumias comment).

Comment: Thanks for answer but it doesnt work. f2Frame is null

Comment: What's about var f2Frame = parent.frames[1][0]?

Comment: This works: var f2Frame = $('frame[name="f2"]');
and even if I add .contentDocument or .contentWindow.document . I still cant get content of the frame

Comment: top.document.querySelector("[name=f2]").contentWindow.document.title should work. It's tested.

The reason why you can't get $("...").contentWindow is that the $() function returns a jQuery object. You could use $('frame[name="f2"]')[0] instead. This returns the appropriate HTMLElement.

Comment: I have tried your code and it doesnt do anything... I want to get one exact element from that frame and work with it (do some jquery stuff on it)

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to alter the title of that frame.
With top.document.querySelector("[name=f2]").contentWindow.document you should have access to the frame's document. In my test case I have. Then you can select that element: var frame2Document = top.document.querySelector("[name=f2]").contentWindow.document;
var up = frame2Document.querySelector("a.myA");
var $up = $(up);
$up.doSomething();
I'm not sure if you have to take this long path or if you can select it directly via jQuerys $().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $up = $(window['f2'].document).find('a.myA');
```

Comment: It would be worth to mention that the outcome of this code is subject to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)